# Google Sheets, convert "2020-January" to "2020-01" and so on

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column with data like "2020-January", "2020-February" and so on. I want to transform the data into "2020-01" , "2020-02" , how could I go about it?

I have tried month(&1), but that seems to only transform "January", but if the year value like 2020 is present, the formula fails.

Comment: If this would be Excel, my first question would be if the mentioned dates are recognised as dates (which you can verify by subtracting 1 and see if you get a correct result), or are those dates just seen as plain strings (in that case you need to do some basic string handling routines).

Answer (score 0):

If your data are stored as `date` then use below formula.

```
=TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm")
```

If data are stored as text then use below formula.

```
=TEXT("1-" & MID(A1,6,3) & "-" & LEFT(A1,4),"yyyy-mm")
```